# Karate API Test - Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience <number> is invalid"

Tags: azure, api, token, karate

[Postman headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIerx.png) I'm using secret keys to generate an access token that I will use to authenticate for an API that I call. The issue is that I'm getting the error:

status code was: 401, expected: 200
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience `value` is invalid"

This is how I call the API

```
Given url `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/token`
And form field grant_type = `client_credentials`
And form field client_id = `value`
And form field client_secret = `value`
When method post
Then status 200

match response.access_token != null

def access_token = response.access_token

print access_token

Given header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + access_token
Given url 'url'
And header accept = `plain/text`
And header 'X-Mimic-User' = `confidential`
When method GET
Then status 200
```

I'm expecting to the authenticated to the API with the generated access token.

Comment: I don't know the details of the API you are calling so I can't help. see if any of these help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bkarate%5d%20oauth

Comment: It's a swagger API hosted in AWS

Comment: The error is specific to your auth endpoint, but you failed to include that value in this ticket, so we don't even know if you're passing it.  Additionally we don't know if the failure is on the POST or the GET.  You need to provide enough information for someone to be able to assist you.

Comment: The failure is on GET, a token is being generated on POST but fails to authenticate when used on GET. The endpoint is correct. It works on Postman. Here's the url <domain>/api/investment-research/v1/Analysts

Comment: @ThabisoDitabe you may be missing a header. try adding `Accept` because Postman auto-adds it, Karate does not. other than that I don't think there is enough information here for anyone to help you, all the best

Comment: @PeterThomas I'm running this on VPN and if I disconnect the VPN, it's a pass and I get an html response with <h3>Error. Page cannot be displayed. Please contact your service provider for more details.  (21)</h3>.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

So it appears your error may be related to the `Authorization` header, although the error description is hard to decipher, possibly scope related?  I would list the URL first, not the header, unless you are re-using it, and want to `configure` the value for subsequent requests.  Another way of setting the Bearer token is:

```
And match response.access_token == '#present'

* def oauthToken = `Bearer ${response.access_token}`
```

But really the most important thing is for you to check your request, including headers and compare it between Karate and Postman to see what is different.

Comment: I've attached the Postman header @anutter

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the error description, the first API call made towards your auth provider is returning a `200` with an access token. but the second call you are making to your application server seems to be failing to see the audience value in your access token.

I doubt you are using the same client credentials input (`client_id`, `client_secret`) in your postman and karate setup. Make sure they are the same.

I would also confirm if the access token received is having the `aud` parameter by checking it in https://jwt.io or any other tool you trust to decode your access token JWT. for the sake of experimentation do the same for the access token you got from postman as well.

Ideally, these configurations are very internal to your application and identity team and may not be directly related to karate. The other teams mentioned should be the ones best to guide you.

Comment: I was actually missing a resource and scope on the header. Thank you.